# Is it true that $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: |1-f(x)|\leq 1-a\} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}: |f(x)|\geq a\}?$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}.$
Let $a$ be a positive constant.

> *Question*: Is it true that 
>   $$\{x\in \mathbb{R}: |1-f(x)|\leq 1-a\} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}: |f(x)|\geq a\}?$$

Observe that $1-f$ is the reflection of $f$ about the line $y=\frac{1}{2}.$
I use desmos to check the two sets and it seems that they coincide.

I tried to prove the equality. 
Let $x$ be a real number such that 
$$|1-f(x)|\leq 1-a.$$
By reverse triangle inequality, 
$$1-|f(x)|\leq |1-f(x)|\leq 1-a.$$
So we have 
$$|f(x)|\ge a.$$
However, if $x$ is such that $|f(x)|\geq a,$ then I am not able to obtain 
$$|1-f(x)|\leq 1-a.$$
It seems that I need 
$$|1-f(x)|\leq 1-|f(x)|$$
but the inequality above may not be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at a simple case:

$f(x) = x$. And let's take $a = 0$.

Then you're asking if the set
$$
\{ x \in R : |1-x| \le 1\} 
$$
is the same as the set 
$$
\{x : |x| \ge 0\}
$$

Well...$x = 3$ is in the second set, but not the first, so the conjecture is false.

Comment: But I am assuming that $a>0.$ Anyway, a slight modification still shows that my conjecture is false.

Comment: Right. Change $a$ to $0.01$ and the $x = 3$ example still demonstrates the difference between the sets.